Block/Unblock chat functionality in Azure Communication Service
We are using Azure Communication Service to allow users of our app to chat.
We are now trying to implement the block/unblock functionality, so when a user blocks another user, the user who is blocking is removed from the chat thread. This way the other used doesn't get notified and can still write in the chat. If the user later decides to unblock, the user it's added back to the chat thread.
The problem is that the user then receives all the messages sent by the blocked user during the time they were blocked.
We want to achive the common block functionality from other apps like Whatsapp, Messenger...
Is that possible to achive using Communication Service?
